# does CSV Writer in append mode bring full file to RAM?

Tags: java, export-to-csv, opencsv

I am using open CSV to write my data to a CSV file. As I know my data is large, I was extracting paginated data from the database and using writeNext to add the data to CSV. Does the full file gets loaded to RAM? or will it append data from the address? if it loads the full file the pagination is useless right.

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
      <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
      <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

```
       CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(target, true));
        for(String[] row : data){
            csvWriter.writeNext(row);
        }
        csvWriter.close();
        return target;
```

Comment: You can download the source and see for yourself? I'd assume it does not read it to memory, as that would be silly, but you can only be user if you *check*.

Comment: Note that CsvWriter isn’t writing to the File directly itself, but writing to the FileWriter - so your question would really be does FileWriter load the whole file into memory when opened for append.  In my time, I have appended to some BIG files that would surely have caused problems of they were while loaded into memory, so for sure the answer is no - as Rob says above, the alternative is silly.